# How can I convert t and f values in numeric in python Dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, data-science, one-hot-encoding

```
A  B
t  f
t  t
f  f
t  t
```

How to convert this kind of data in numeric form in python for multiple columns?

Answer (score 2):

You could [`replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) the values using a dictionary:

```py
df[['A', 'B']] = df[['A', 'B']].replace({ 't': 1, 'f': 0 })
```

Output:

```
   A  B
0  1  0
1  1  1
2  0  0
3  1  1
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`factorize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.factorize.html) with [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) for numeric columns by categories:

```
cols = ['A','B']

y, label = pd.factorize(df[cols].stack())

df[cols] = y.reshape(df[cols].shape)
print (df)
   A  B
0  0  1
1  0  0
2  1  1
3  0  0
```

Dictionary for mapping is possible generate by:

```
d = dict(zip(label, y))
print (d)
{'t': 0, 'f': 1}
```

Answer (score 0):

the first thing i came to was using factorize, but as it's already given above i came to the second:

```
df = df.stack().to_frame().apply(lambda x: pd.Categorical(x).codes).unstack().droplevel(0,1)

>>> df
'''
   A  B
0  1  0
1  1  1
2  0  0
3  1  1
```